# Difference in working of python urllib2 for http and https urls

Tags: python, urllib2

Can someone explain to me why things are implemented the following in urllib2.

When I pass encoded url using http it again encodes the parameters
whereas in case of https it does not urlencode again

so lets say the (http) call is http//:example.com?email=amit%40sethi.com the request is

http://example.com?email=amit%2540sethi.com

where as in case of https it is

https://example.com?email=amit%40sethi.com

Thanks

Edit : Adding more details

The basic request I am making is

```
SF_EXTEND_RESOURCE = "https://www.superfax.in/api/voice/planchange/?"

params_dict = {'username':USERNAME,
                               'password':PASSWORD,
                               'email':str(user.email)
                               }
_url = SF_EXTEND_RESOURCE + urlencode(params_dict)
response = urllib2.urlopen(_url).read()
```

Now my problem is that when I am using http the email string is encoded twice where as that was not the case for https . I am using Python 2.6.5 on ubuntu Lucid. I am not able to understand how this is not reproducible.

Comment: Can't reproduce this, after opening an URL both with http and https the query string isn't encoded again in any case. Please post the actual code you're using and/or how you came to this conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it, and for me the behaviour is not what you observe: for me, http and https URLs work the same.

```
import urllib2

out = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google.com/?q=foo%40bar");
print out.geturl()
open('out1', 'w').write(out.read())
out = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/?q=foo%40bar");
print out.geturl()
open('out2', 'w').write(out.read())
```

Compare `out1` and `out2` and you'll find that both the correct foo@bar in the "value" attribute of the search box, so there doesn't seem to be any double-encoding going on.